# When is Tensor Zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I find it generally troublesome to show that an element in $A \otimes_R B$ is zero or nonzero (where $A$ is a right $R$-module and $B$ is a left $R$-module), because even though an element may not seem like it's zero, there could be some relation to kill the element. More precisely, I'd like to prove the following statement I encountered while studying group cohomology:

**Claim.** 
Suppose $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of finite index: $G = g_1 H \cup \cdots \cup g_n H$. Suppose $A$ is a left $H$-module. Then every element of $\mathbb{Z}[G]\otimes_{\mathbb Z[H]} A$ can be uniquely written as $g_1 \otimes a_1 + \cdots + g_n \otimes a_n$. In particular, $g_1 \otimes a_1 + \cdots g_n \otimes a_n = 0 \implies a_1 = \cdots = a_n = 0$.

It's easy to see that every element of $\mathbb{Z}[G]\otimes_{\mathbb Z[H]} A$ admits such a form. However, I'm really not sure how I'm supposed to prove uniqueness of such expression, i.e. $g_1 \otimes a_1 + \cdots g_n \otimes a_n = 0 \implies a_1 = \cdots = a_n = 0$.

Comment: What is $A$? $\space$

Comment: Sorry I'll add in some details.

Comment: Is this really true?  What if $G$ is finite and $H$ is the trivial group?

Comment: From what I can see, it still seems to be true because elements of $G$ in $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ are "free" from each other. Please enlighten me with a counterexample if I'm missing anything.

Comment: What if $G = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, $H=0$, and $A = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}] \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, every element can be written as $\sigma \otimes k_1 + \sigma^2 \otimes k_2 + \sigma^3 \otimes k_3$ (where elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}]$ are represented as $u_1 \sigma + u_2 \sigma^2 + u_3 \sigma^3$) and I don't think it's possible to have $\sigma \otimes k_1 + \sigma^2 \otimes k_2 + \sigma^3 \otimes k_3=0$ without having $k_1 = k_2 = k_3 = 0$.